# Change every single letter to uppercase and enclose it into brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

As title says, I am trying to make a script which will find every single letter into a string, for example the " a " or " A " letter into a sentence, change it to uppercase and enclose it into brackets. For example, "I bought [A] soccer ball".

I'll use this script into a renamer application which is doing various stuff using Javascript. So I have those two scripts...

```
return item.newBasename.replace(/(?=.{1}$)/,'[');
```

and..

```
return item.newBasename.replace(/(?=.{0}$)/,']');
```

which basically do what I want in some way, but it's like I work manually!!!

**EDIT**

This renamer application gives me by default this...

```
function(index, item) { }
```

and I have to write my code into this which looks like this...

```
function(index, item) {return item.newBasename...etc}
```

Comment: You two lines wrap the last char in the string with `[...]`. Is that what you need? However, your example is different.

Comment: *find every single letter into a string* Do you mean, single letter word?

Comment: I would assume `"[I] bought [A] soccer ball"` unless you mean all single letter words that are lowercase - which is basically `a` I guess - in which case Paul Fitzgerald's now deleted answer was correct ;)

Comment: Try `str.replace(/(^| )([a-z])($| )/g, function($0, $1, $2, $3) { return $1 + '[' + $2.toUpperCase() + ']' + $3; })`

Comment: @revo This is a proper answer. You should post it there.

Comment: Or `str = str.replace(/(^|\s)([a-z])(?!\S)/g, function($0,$1,$2) { return $1 + '[' + $2.toUpperCase() + ']'; })` if there can be consecutive single letter words.

Comment: After your edit, seems you just want `item.newBasename.replace(/^.$/, function ($0) { return '[' + $0.toUpperCase() + ']'; })`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `(^| )([a-z])(?=$| )` as the regex along with `toUpperCase()` method:

```js
var str = 'i bought a soccer ball';
console.log(str.replace(/(^| )([a-z])(?=$| )/g, function($0, $1, $2) {
    return $1 + '[' + $2.toUpperCase() + ']';
}));
```

Regex breakdown:

- `(^| )` Capture beginning of input string or a space character
- `([a-z])` Capture a lower case letter
- `(?=$| )` Followed by end of string or a space character, same as `(?!\S)`

Comment: I can understand that your code is correct but I can't apply it... Please take a look at my question I added more informations!!! Thank you for your time!!!

Comment: Does `item` contain one word at a time?

Comment: The "item" is the full name of a file!

Comment: So do you mean it could contain `this is a file name`? What does `item.newBasename` hold?

Comment: The name of the file!

Comment: It seems you only need to replace `str.replace...` with `item.newBasename.replace...`.

Comment: I also have problem with `[a-z]`. I want brackets for `[a-z]` and `[A-Z]` too! What is the syntax for this?

Comment: OK it worked. In my case I had to do like this: `return item.newBasename.replace(/(^| )([a-z, A-Z])(?=$| )/g, function($0, $1, $2) {return $1 + '[' + $2.toUpperCase() + ']';})`. Thank you very much for time!!!

Comment: That's not the correct way. You only need to add `i` flag: `/(^| )([a-z])(?=$| )/gi`

Answer (score 2):

A solution without using `regex`:

```js
var inputStr = "i bought a soccer ball"

var outputStr = inputStr.split(' ')  // separete each words
                        .map(w => w.length === 1 ? '[' + w.toUpperCase() + ']' : w)  // uppercase single letters
                        .join(' ')  // join them with single space

console.log(outputStr);
```

Comment: Don't forget brackets

Answer (score 2):

You can use word boundery and find single letters easily like `\b(\w)\b` :-

```
function formatSentence(sentence){
    return sentence.replace(/\b(\w)\b/g, 
        function($0) {
        return '[' + $0.toUpperCase() + ']';
    })
}
```